# Content block position problems

Tags: html, css, silverstripe

i have a content block module in my SilverStripe. All works fine, but i need design that my content blocks are floating left.  I want to do something like this -> [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_inline-block_old)

But the float do not work properly. It displays my blocks in vertical line.

**css:**

```
.BoxPage { 

    float: left;

        }
.BoxPage5   { 

    height: 400px; 
    width: 600px;
    line-height: 2.0em;
                    }
```

**BoxPage html**

```
<div class="BoxPage5">
    <% loop $Blocks %> <- this loop blocks
    $HTML <- this insert block content (images, title, link) 
<% end_loop %>
</div>
```

**IamgeBlock html:**

```
<% loop $Images.Sort('SortOrder') %> <- This loop images
<a href="$Top.WebsiteLinkHyper"> <- This add a href link
<div class="BoxPage3"> <- This is for opacity effect. 
<figure>
<h2>$Title</h2> 
    $Tag  
</figure>
</div>
</a>
<% end_loop %>
```

I know that i am doing this wrong, but what exactly am i doing wrong ?

Also a question how i should in this case add a specific size to content ? For example content blocks are only 600px horizontaly and 300px verticaly. 
`height: 400px;`  and `width: 600px` in my case did not do the thing correctly. 
Sorry for noob questions and bad English language.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested your code, but it looks like you need to give each of your block instances its own div container, e.g.:

```
<div class="BoxPage5">
    <% loop $Blocks %>
        <div class="BoxPage">$HTML</div>
    <% end_loop %>
</div>
```

On a side note, I'd also recommend using a class naming convention like [BEM](http://getbem.com/naming/), or the lowercase BEM style that Bootstrap uses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already made it work by addind a <figure> css